# Verificar continencia lista python

Tags: python

Gostaria de ajuda com um código.

```
lista1 = [5, 6, 7]
lista2 = [4, 'a', 9, 5, 6, 7]
```

Verificar se a lista1 (a lista toda) está contida em lista2

e se

```
lista2 = [4, 9, 5, 'a', 6, 7]
```

fazer a mesma verificação, mas agora é negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Crie dois `set`'s (conjunto de elementos sem repetições) e use o método `issubset`.

```
lista1 = [5, 6, 7]
lista2 = [4, 'a', 9, 5, 6, 7]

set1 = set(lista1)
set2 = set(lista2)

if(set1.issubset(set2)):
    print('lista1 está contida em lista2')
else:
    print('lista1 não está contida em lista2')
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/Hopi)

Comment: Mas quando eu substituo lista2 = [4, 9, 5, 'a', 6, 7], continua dizendo que a lista pertence e não deveria.

Comment: @fnetto Deveria sim, ora. Ainda tem 5, 6, 7 na lista.

Comment: Pelo comentário, acredito que ele queira que a verificação seja se o conteúdo da lista1 está na lista2 na mesma sequência

Comment: Pois é, @Fabiano. Mas eu precisaria ter certeza pra responder sobre.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre verificar se todos os elementos da lista 1 estão contidos na lista 2, você pode criar um **for** para andar por todos os elementos da lista 1 e usar um **in** para analisar se eles estão na lista 2, caso eles não estejam, você pode sinalizar.

Da uma olhada nesse código

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

# Listas que serão comparadas
lista1 = [1,2,3,4]
lista2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

# Variável de referência
estaContido = 1

# Vamos andar por todos os elementos da lista 1
for n in lista1:
 # Se o elemento N da lista 1 estiver contido na Lista 2
 if n in lista2:
  # Passe direto
  pass
 # Se não(Algum elemento da lista 1 não está contido na lista 2)
 else:
  # Mudamos o valor da referência
  estaContido = 0

# Se todos os elementos da lista 1 estavam contidos na lista 2
if estaContido == 1:
 print("Lista 1 está contido na lista 2")
else:
 print("Lista 1 NÃO está contida na lista 2")
```